# Deducing the "outer class" of a class with Template Argument Deduction

Tags: c++

```cpp
class Component_Base{};

class Rect_Component : Component_Base
{
public:
    struct Info
    {
        uInt width;
        uInt height;
    };
};

template<typename... Args>
class ECSData
{
private:
    tuple<optional_ECSVector_wrapped_t<Args>...> data;

public:

    template<typename... Info>
    void createEntity(Info&&... info) {
    }
};

int main()
{
    ECSData<Rect_Component, Text_Component, Rendering_System> ecsData;
    ecsData.createEntity(Rect_Component::Info{ .width{200}, .height{500} });
    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, I'm passing `Rect_Component::Info` to `createEntity()`.
Given the code above, would be possible inside `createEntity()` to have Template Argument Deduction deduce what `T` in `T::Info` is, and use said T?
After all I'm writing `Rect_Component` in the call, so I am suspecting there must be a way

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
struct Not_Rect_Component {
    using Info = Rect_Component::Info;
};
```

This can't be distinguished from the `Info` provided by your original `Rect_Component`, so you can't deduce one or the other. You have to provide a typedef inside `Info` which refers to the correct parent type.

Comment: *"a typedef inside `Info`"*. or an external type traits.